# A way to hide attributes with Symfony Normalizer

Tags: php, symfony, normalization

I have object A :

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private ?string $bar;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private ?string $foo;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private ?string $mustBeHidden;
}
```

I use the Symfony normalizer to return to the end-users the object A as indicated in my model.

My Serializer configuration:

```
$this->serializer = new Serializer(
    [
        new DateTimeNormalizer(),
        ...$this->normalizers,
        new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor()),
        new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    ],
    [new JsonEncoder(new JsonEncode(), new JsonDecode())]
);
```

I return my object in this way:

```
return (array) $this->serializer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
```

Goals:

1. I want to hide some attributes of my object A while keeping my
   Normalizer, is it possible?

I don't want to create a custom object that will contain only the properties I want to display.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes

```
[AbstractNormalizer::IGNORED_ATTRIBUTES => ['mustBeHidden']]
```

I tried to use the annotations (https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#option-1-using-ignore-annotation) directly in my model but it did not work.